# If Then, concatenate when condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, concatenation, formula

I want to simplify an everyday work task.  I am looking for a macro or a formula that will look at `Column C`, and if *New* is present, combine `N` with the data from `Column A`; if *Used* is present, combine `U` with the data from `Column A`.

**Before:**

```
      A         B         c
   123456                New
   234657                Used
   345678                New
```

**After:**

```
     A         B         c
   123456   N123456     New
   234657   U234567     Used
   345678   N345678     New
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case where its not a matter of IF in column C  but just whatever the first letter of column C is, drop the IF portion and go straight to the concatenation.

```
=LEFT(C1)&A1
```

Comment: This is definitely the best for simplicity. If you want to have it returned blank if either contributing field is blank, I would try this: `=IF(OR(C1="",A1=""),"",LEFT(C1)&A1)`

Comment: when I tested, the left of a blank was blank.  it did not throw an error.

Comment: I hadn't tested either. Mine wasn't so much to prevent errors, as to just prevent "Premature Concatenation". It's a real problem...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are *only* New and Used, this can go in `B1` and drag down.

```
=IF(C1="New","N"&A1,"U"&A1)
```

If there are other options, then you can use this one:

```
=IF(C1="New","N"&A1,IF(C1="Used","U"&A1,""),"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate:

```
=IF(OR(C1={"New","Used"}),LEFT(C1)&A1,"")
```

Comment: I assume `LEFT()` just defaults to the first character? Didn't realize that.  Clever answer! This would also be more easily scalable than my answer, if there are other words to add.